# store multiple image through two input types in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

> I want to store multiple image through two input type,but one input type post has store and another input post value not stored.

my view

```
<span class="btn btn-round" title="Upload Photo">                                                                    
<input type="file" name="photo[]" multiple="">                                                                  
</span>
<span class="btn btn-round" title="Upload Photo">                                                                    
<input type="file" name="doc[]" multiple="">                                                                  
</span>
```

> my controller

```
             if (!empty($_FILES['photo']['name'])) {
            $filesCount = count($_FILES['photo']['name']);          
            for ($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {
                $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['photo']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['photo']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['photo']
                           ['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['photo']['error']
                                         [$i];
                $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['photo']['size'][$i];

                $uploadPath = 'assets/uploads/';
                $type = 'photo';
                $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|png|jpg|jpeg';

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if ($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')) {
                    $getdata = $this->upload->data();
                    $uploadData[$i] = $getdata['file_name'];
                }
            }
        }
        if(!empty($_FILES['doc']['name'])){
            $filesCounts = count($_FILES['doc']['name']);echo $filesCounts;
            for ($j = 0; $j < $filesCounts; $j++) {
                $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['doc']['name'][$j];
                $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['doc']['type'][$j];
                $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['doc']['tmp_name']
                                                                  [$j];
                $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['doc']['error'][$j];
                $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['doc']['size'][$j];

                $uploadPaths = 'assets/uploads/';
                $type1 = 'document';
                $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
                $config['allowed_types'] =                       
                   'gif|png|jpg|jpeg|pdf|xls|docx|xlsx';
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if ($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')) {
                    $getdata = $this->upload->data();
                    $uploadDocument[$j] = $getdata['file_name'];
                }
            }
        }
              for ($r = 0; $r < count($uploadData); $r++) {
                $data3 = array('event_id' => $last_id, 'file_name' => 
              $uploadData[$r], 'file_path' => $uploadPath, 'content_type' => 
              $type);
              if ($data3['file_name'] != "") {
              $this->admin_model->insert_activity_photo($data3);
              }
              }
              for ($a = 0; $a < count($uploadDocument); $a++) {
            $data5 = array('event_id' => $last_id, 'file_name' => 
         $uploadDocument[$a], 'file_path' => $uploadPaths, 'content_type' => 
         $type1);
        if ($data5['file_name'] != "") {
            $this->admin_model->insert_activity_photo($data5);
        }
        }
```

> my model

```
function insert_activity_photo($data3 = array()){
    $this->db->insert('t_attachment',$data3);
}
function insert_activity_photos($data5 = array()){
    $this->db->insert('t_attachment',$data5);
}
```

> when i try to store multiple image from this two input types only first input type value has posted second input type value not posted.

Answer (score 1):

Hi the both image starting position is 0($I=0 and $j=0) so the file is replace you should change the key kindly check my code
$uploadDocument[$k]

```
 if (!empty($_FILES['photo']['name'])) {
        $filesCount = count($_FILES['photo']['name']); 
         $k=0;         
        for ($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {

            $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['photo']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['photo']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['photo']
                       ['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['photo']['error']
                                     [$i];
            $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['photo']['size'][$i];

            $uploadPath = 'assets/uploads/';
            $type = 'photo';
            $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|png|jpg|jpeg';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')) {
                $getdata = $this->upload->data();
                $uploadData[$k] = $getdata['file_name'];
            }
          $k++;
        }
    }
    if(!empty($_FILES['doc']['name'])){
        $filesCounts = count($_FILES['doc']['name']);echo $filesCounts;
        for ($j = 0; $j < $filesCounts; $j++) {
            $_FILES['userFile']['name'] = $_FILES['doc']['name'][$j];
            $_FILES['userFile']['type'] = $_FILES['doc']['type'][$j];
            $_FILES['userFile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['doc']['tmp_name']
                                                              [$j];
            $_FILES['userFile']['error'] = $_FILES['doc']['error'][$j];
            $_FILES['userFile']['size'] = $_FILES['doc']['size'][$j];

            $uploadPaths = 'assets/uploads/';
            $type1 = 'document';
            $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
            $config['allowed_types'] =                       
               'gif|png|jpg|jpeg|pdf|xls|docx|xlsx';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            if ($this->upload->do_upload('userFile')) {
                $getdata = $this->upload->data();
                $uploadDocument[$k] = $getdata['file_name'];
            }
           $k++;
        }
    }
          for ($r = 0; $r < count($uploadData); $r++) {
            $data3 = array('event_id' => $last_id, 'file_name' => 
          $uploadData[$r], 'file_path' => $uploadPath, 'content_type' => 
          $type);
          if ($data3['file_name'] != "") {
          $this->admin_model->insert_activity_photo($data3);
          }
          }
          for ($a = 0; $a < count($uploadDocument); $a++) {
              $data5 = array('event_id' => $last_id, 'file_name' => 
              $uploadDocument[$a], 'file_path' => $uploadPaths, 'content_type' => $type1);
             if ($data5['file_name'] != "") {
                 $this->admin_model->insert_activity_photo($data5);
             }
    }
```